# Search in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as below:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {
        'employee_id': ['4444', '5555', '6666','7777','8888'],
        'first_name': ['aa', 'Jason', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Millers', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'],
        'age': [42, 42, 36, 24, 73],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['employee_id','first_name', 'last_name', 'age'])


raw_data1 = {'employee_id': ['4444', '5555', '6666','7777'],
    'ip': ['192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.102','192.168.1.103','192.168.1.104'], 

}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1, columns = ['employee_id', 'ip'])
```

I have to search (compare) `df2['employee_id']` in df1 and if values are the same, add `df2['ip']` to df1 as:

```
print df2['ip'].where(df2['employee_id']==df1['employee_id'])
```

But this isn't the right method:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

any suggestion for this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an updated answer as someone deleted the post with what I thought was the better solution.

```
on = "employee_id"
df3 = df1.set_index(on).join(df2.set_index(on)).fillna("IP missing")
df3["ip"].to_dict()

employee_id first_name  last_name   age ip          
4444        aa          Miller      42  192.168.1.101
5555        Jason       Millers     42  192.168.1.102
6666        Tina        Ali         36  192.168.1.103
7777        Jake        Milner      24  192.168.1.104
8888        Amy         Cooze       73  IP missing

{'4444': '192.168.1.101',
'5555': '192.168.1.102',
'6666': '192.168.1.103',
'7777': '192.168.1.104',
'8888': 'IP missing'}
```

Previous answer:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on="employee_id")
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging

> pd.merge(left, right, how='inner', on=None, left_on=None,
>   right_on=None,
>            left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=True,
>            suffixes=('_x', '_y'), copy=True, indicator=False)

Gives

```
    employee_id first_name  last_name   age ip
0   4444    aa      Miller  42  192.168.1.101
1   5555    Jason   Millers 42  192.168.1.102
2   6666    Tina    Ali 36  192.168.1.103
3   7777    Jake    Milner  24  192.168.1.104
```

And possibly you want something like this:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on="employee_id").set_index("employee_id")["ip"].to_dict()

{'4444': '192.168.1.101',
 '5555': '192.168.1.102',
 '6666': '192.168.1.103',
 '7777': '192.168.1.104'}
```

Comment: what about if I want to add matching value to df1 : adding one column and insert matching ip, the row that doesn't match would be empty. Thanks

Comment: @jojo Reassign it here: on = "employee_id", df1 = df1.set_index(on).join(df2.set_index(on)).reset_index()

Comment: your data science knowledge is awesome. Could you please suggest some books or video tutorials? I'm python developer but completely new in data science. Thank you

Comment: @jojo Glad to hear but I'm no data scientist, I'm just programming in my work (for fun, and the fact it is more effective) and thought I could learn more by helping others.

Answer (score 2):

Use `merge`

```
In [1286]: df1.merge(df2, on='employee_id')
Out[1286]:
  employee_id first_name last_name  age             ip
0        4444         aa    Miller   42  192.168.1.101
1        5555      Jason   Millers   42  192.168.1.102
2        6666       Tina       Ali   36  192.168.1.103
3        7777       Jake    Milner   24  192.168.1.104
```

Comment: I've wondered for some time, how did you copy to get that output so nicely formatted?

Comment: I'm mostly on Jupyter, do you know the trick there? What are the steps? Anyway you get my upvote +1.

Comment: @maxU Thanks! yes I understood that but how about Jupyter? Do you know?